# std::vector<float> to std::vector<glm::vecX> without copying

Tags: c++, vector, struct, glm-math

I am writing a small toy game engine using [Tinyobjloader](https://github.com/syoyo/tinyobjloader) for loading .obj files. I store the vertex data and everything using [glm](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.7/index.html)::vecX to make things easier.

Tinyobjloader gives me an `std::vector<float>`, when I want an `std::vector<glm::vecX>`. How would I do this without copying?

To be clear, a `glm::vecX` is a simple struct containing, for example, the `float` members `x, y, z`.

I was thinking that since structs can behave a bit like arrays, that [std::move](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) would work, but no luck.

Thanks!

Edit:
I know I wasn't clear about this, sorry. I would like to either move the `std::vector<float>` into an `std::vector<glm::vecX>` or pass it as a `std::vector<glm::vecX>&`.

Copying the data using `std::memcpy` works fine, but it copies the data, which I would like to avoid.

Comment: You have to create your own function to achieve that (it costs you 1 for)

Comment: What is the definition of `glm::vecX`?

Comment: What are the types of the members `x`, `y`, and `z`? What should the corresponding `float` values be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be possible to *directly interpret* the contents of the vector as instances of the struct, without having to copy the data. If you can guarantee the representation is compatible, that is. The contents of a `vector<float>` are laid out in memory as a sequence of float values directly following each other (an array) with no extra padding, while the contents of a `vector<glm::vecX>` are laid out as a sequence of vecX. Thus, you need to ensure the following conditions hold:

- That `glm::vecX` is exactly the size of X floats, with no padding. Depending on the declaration of the struct, this may be platform-dependant.
- That the contents of the `vector<float>` are in the correct sequence, i.e. as [x1,y1,z1, x2,y2,z2, ...] for a vec3 instead of [x1,x2,...,xN,y1,y2...].

In that case, you can safely reinterpret the data pointer of the float vector as pointer to an array of vecX as in this example:

```
std::vector<float> myObjData = ...;
auto nVecs = myObjData.size() / 3; // You should check that there are no remainders!
glm::vec3* vecs = reinterpret_cast<glm::vec3*>(myObjData.data());
std::cout << vecs[0]; // Use vecs[0..nVecs-1]
```

You cannot, however, safely reinterpret the *vector* itself as a vector of glm::vecX, *not even as a const vector*, because the number of elements stored in the vector might not be consistent after the reinterpretation. It depends on whether the `vector<T>` code stores the number of elements directly, or the number of allocated bytes (and then size() divides that by sizeof(T)):

```
// Don't do this, the result of .size() and .end() may be wrong!
const std::vector<glm::vec3>& bad = *reinterpret_cast<std::vector<glm::vec3>*>(&myObjData);
bad[bad.size()-1].z = 0; // Potential BOOM!
```

Most of the time, however, you don't need to pass an actual *vector*, since most functions in the standard library accept a *container range*, which is easy to give for arrays like the one in the first example. So, if you wanted to sort your vec3 array based on z position, and then print it out you would do:

```
// nVecs and vecs from the first example
std::sort(vecs, vecs+nVecs, // Sort by Z position
    [](const glm::vec3& a, const glm::vec3& b) { return a.z < b.z; });
std::copy(vecs, vecs+nVecs, std::ostream_iterator<glm::vec3>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

Comment: Oooo, fancy! Since `glm::vecX` is supposed to be paddingless (that's the point of glm). Now, of course, as you said, this could be platform-dependant, so I'll be checking for that before using it. [Check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13571898/c-opengl-glm-and-struct-padding) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33058927/how-does-opengl-fill-buffers-and-read-them-back) for more information on this.

Answer (score 0):

**In short:** It is - to the best of my knowledge - not possible without copying.

And in my opinion, `std::memcpy` has no business being used with `std::vector`.